# CSRF Cookie Not Set

Tags: python, django, csrf

I have problem with Django CSRF. When I try to register new user or log in I get the next error: CSRF cookie not set. Also on the register page the username and web-site label's don't load correctly, I get symbols like this: 'Ð˜Ð¼Ñ Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ»Ñ' instead.

I have already tried CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True,django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware, clearing browser data, my {% csrf_token %}  is placed inside the form. Could anyone give me at least some hints about possible errors?
My code:

forms.py:

```
 <form method="post" action="register/">
 {% csrf_token %}         
 {{ user_form.as_p }}
 {{ profile_form.as_p }}
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
registered = False
if request.method == 'POST':

    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        registered = True                  
    else:
        print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()
return render_to_response(
        'register.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered}, c)
```

Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: You shouldn’t have `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` unless you are serving the site over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use `render_to_response`, it’s obsolete. Use `render` instead.

```
return render(request,
    'register.html',
    {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered})
```

You can then remove these lines from the view:

```
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
```